# git push origin master asking for remote server password

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I installed gitlab on my local machine. It installed fine. When I run the

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

Every check passes.
I created a project and a user in gitlab. When I run following command

```
git push origin master
```

It asks for remote server password as

```
enter password for git@gitserver
```

I configured my gitlab installation on gitserver. I edited the hosts file under etc/hosts to point gitserver to 127.0.0.1

I verified my ssh key is properly set. I also check /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.
Puclic key authentication is on as

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I don't know what I am missing. I suppose the problem is because of congifuring gitlab to use gitserver. 
How can I resolve this problem ?

```
/var/logs/auth.log tail view

May 14 00:25:30 sabertooth sshd[6276]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost  user=git
May 14 00:25:32 sabertooth sshd[6276]: Failed password for git from 127.0.0.1 port 16139 ssh2
May 14 00:25:50 sabertooth sshd[6276]: Failed password for git from 127.0.0.1 port 16139 ssh2
May 14 00:25:50 sabertooth sshd[6276]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
May 14 00:25:50 sabertooth sshd[6276]: PAM 1 more authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=localhost  user=git
```

Also I missed one step from installation guide

```
 3. System Users

Create a git user for Gitlab:

sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git
```

Because when I tried to run this command I am getting that user git already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked permissions that gitlab uses from you home dir?
Also to do configuration you need to switch to user git in the first step with:

```
su -git
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: ok, with which user you are doing following command git push origin master, make sure you are switched to user git before this

Comment: I am doing this command with default user i.e, my user name. If I switch to git also I am getting same error.

Comment: I don't remember. Do I have to remove the user and recreate it

Comment: yes, try to recreate teh git user according to docummentation

Comment: I tried eveyting it is still asking for remote server password